SharePoint Online - Isolation in Prod and Pre Prod Environments
Currently we are on SharePoint 2019 On Prem with 5 Web Apps(Around 40 site collections and 200 subsites overall). We have several OOB sites, few nintex forms and workflows and few(around 20) Custom wsp solutions
Our organization is moving to SharePoint online and I would like to know how do you keep Dev, QA, Stage and Prod environments isolated? (in SP 2019 we had a separate farm for each environment)

Posts which are several years older pointed to have separate SharePoint online tenants for each, but recent posts suggest a single tenant. What would be pros and cons of single vs multi tenant, which is recommended one?

We currently have few server side wsp solutions(farm scoped, web app scope, event recievers), what are good alternatives since server is not supported in SPO


Note : We have single tenant at our organization currently which is being used for generic purposes.
